# Power Query returns login form as resultset instead of content even after authentication

Tags: authentication, https, powerbi, powerquery

I am trying to scrape a website resultset to create a table with the results from that specific site. On normal login on this site i can use my credentials to access the contents of the site. Site uses HTTPS

However, when i am trying to retrieve the content of this same site through power BI (and more specific Power Query) I am presented with a resultset of two columns and two rows as if the site was asking me for credentials:

```
|--------------|-------------|
|  Username:   |             |
|--------------|-------------|
|  Password:   |             |
|--------------|-------------|
```

This is after i entered my credentials when power query asks for them (not returning any error of faulty input). Credentials are correctly entered. When entering bad credentials it gives an error.

I have tried the following options query wise:

- Direct input of the desired website
- Advanced input with Query and Content optionss in M to force POST() instead of GET().

advanced method 1 - shows login form when executed:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(
        Web.Contents(
            "https://url.htm",
            [Query=
                [mNo ="1234",form name="overviewDetailsForm", id="overviewDetailsForm", method="post"
                ]
            ]
        )
    ),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]
in
    Data0
```

Method 2 - gives an error because option can only be used with anonymous credentials:

```
let
    Source = Web.Page(
        Web.Contents(
            "https://url.htm",
            [Query=
                [mNo ="1234",form name="overviewDetailsForm", id="overviewDetailsForm", method="post"
                ]
            ],
            [Content=Text.ToBinary()
            ]
        )
    ),
    Data0 = Source{0}[Data]
in
    Data0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the HTTP debugger [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) you should be able to inspect the HTTPS request your browser makes on the site. (You'll have to agree to let Fiddler install a root CA on your machine in order to MITM your internet traffic.) Does your username/password show up in the Auth or Headers tab?

You can typically set any header you want in `Web.Contents` and they work with  `Web.Page` too, but be aware that some auth tokens will expire over time.

With some trial and error, you should be able to get Power Query to make the same HTTP request as your browser, and you'll get your data!

Comment: Hi Carl, Thanks for your insights. I have tried fiddler and even with decrypt  HTTPS traffic my username and pass does not show up in the traffic. I am not sure if this is because power query has my credentials stored (because it asks for them the first time when connecting) and generates a token itself or another reason. I will 'Fiddle' around with it but if you more tips that would be great.

Comment: If you look at the traffic from your browser, there needs to be some authentication? Is it using a cookie or some other auth token?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. i totally forgot about this topic to be honest. The issue has not been resolved and will not be resolved. The source which we were trying to resolve uses some auth token for which we will not be granted access to for our application by our customer. i will see to have this thread closed.